# Use JSON object as key in Java Map

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

Can i use json object as key in java maps. Following is want i am looking for:

Map

```
Object1 = { "Key1": "Value1"}

Object2 = { "Key2": "Value2" }
```

So that when i print map it should return

```
{ "Key1": "Value1"} : { "Key2": "Value2" }
```

Here key and value both are JSON.

I tried but i am getting string returned as map key instead of JSON.

```
"{ "\"Key1"\": "\"Value1"\"}" : { "Key2": "Value2" }"
```

I have overridden toString method for this

```
public String toString() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(this); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return super.toString();
    }
}
```

But it does not seem to be working the way i want.

Comment: I don't quite get your problem. Are `Object1` and `Object2` both keys to map? (Btw map keys should never mutable otherwise you could break the map). And with "when i print map it should return ..." do you mean you should get the output you posted? What would `{ "Key1": "Value1"}` be in that case? It looks like key:value but that wouldn't fit your description of using `Object1` as a key etc. And finally, which `toString()` did you override? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: I am also not sure of the goal here: JSON only supports String keys; no other JSON value is allowed as a key. Java does support `Map` keys of arbitrary types; but those must be mapped to Strings for JSON. So... a conversion of some sort is needed.

Comment: Hi @Thomas, Object1 is the key and objects2 is the value here. what i want here is Map whose keys are going to be json object.